# How can I iterate through rows and columns converting only numeric columns into z-scores? in R

Tags: r, statistics, economics

I have a large dataset with several variable types but would like to iterate through and change all of the numeric columns into z-scores to run a standardized regression. Here's some test code & data that I have but it doesn't quite work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
# z = ((x_i-mean(X)) / sd(X))

pet <- c("dog", "cat", "bird", "sheep")
quant <- c(2, 3, 4, 12)
hite <- c(5, 6, 9, 13)
wide <- c(6, 7, 10, 20)
color <- c("red", "blue", "purple", "white")

test <- data.frame(pet, quant, hite, wide, color)

test_z <- test
for (col in 1:ncol(test_z)){
  if(class(names(test_z[1, col])) != "numeric") {
    next()
  } else {
    avg <- mean(test_z[,col])
    std <- sd(test_z[,col])
    for (row in 1:nrow(test_z)) {
      z_score <- (test_z[row,col] - avg) / std
      test_z[row,col] <- z_score
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe use `scale(test[, sapply(test, is.numeric)])`? you might also need `drop=FALSE` if there is a possibility of only 1 numeric column

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to calculate `z_score` and apply it for numeric columns

```
z_score <- function(x) {(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}

cols <- sapply(test, class) == "numeric"
test[cols] <- lapply(test[cols], z_score)
test

#    pet      quant       hite       wide  color
#1   dog -0.7106195 -0.9042908 -0.7425804    red
#2   cat -0.4919673 -0.6260475 -0.5862477   blue
#3  bird -0.2733152  0.2086825 -0.1172495 purple
#4 sheep  1.4759020  1.3216559  1.4460776  white
```

We can also use `dplyr` to apply this

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, z_score)
```

As mentioned by @chinsoon12 as an alternative, we can use `scale` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
test[,sapply(test, is.numeric)] <- lapply(test[,sapply(test, is.numeric)], function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
```